# Why does SimpleDateFormat.format(Date) ignore the configured TimeZone?

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

Given that my default TimeZone is Europe/Paris:

```
System.out.println("Current Timezone: " + TimeZone.getDefault());
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX");

String dateStrIn = "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z";
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateStrIn);
String dateStrOut = dateFormat.format(date);

System.out.println("Input date String: "+dateStrIn);
System.out.println("Date.toString() "+date);
System.out.println("Output date String: "+dateStrOut);
```

The output is:

```
Current Timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Paris",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=184,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Paris,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
Input date String: 2016-08-01T00:00:00Z
Date.toString() Mon Aug 01 02:00:00 CEST 2016
Output date String: 2016-08-01T02:00:00+02
```

Now, I repeat the execution but setting a different default TimeZone (UTC):

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
System.out.println("Current Timezone: " + TimeZone.getDefault());
...
```

And this is the output:

```
Current Timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="UTC",offset=0,dstSavings=0,useDaylight=false,transitions=0,lastRule=null]
Input date String: 2016-08-01T00:00:00Z
Date.toString() Mon Aug 01 00:00:00 UTC 2016
Output date String: 2016-08-01T02:00:00+02
```

`Date.toString()` has correctly taken into account the TimeZone change. However, the String gotten from `dateFormat.format(date);` is still showing +02 instead of Z or +00, why?

Using standard Java API, is there any way to force the formatting according to a selected TimeZone?

**UPDATE:**

Jesper's solution works in almost all cases, but I have come across this one (using Canary Island's summer time zone WEST) in which it doesn't:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z");
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
System.out.println("Current Timezone: " + TimeZone.getDefault());

String dateStrIn = "2016-08-01T08:00:00 WEST";
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateStrIn);
String dateStrOut = dateFormat.format(date);

System.out.println("Input date String: "+dateStrIn);
System.out.println("Date.toString() "+date);
System.out.println("Output date String: "+dateStrOut);
```

Output:

```
Current Timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Paris",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=184,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Paris,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
Input date String: 2016-08-01T08:00:00 WEST
Date.toString() Mon Aug 01 09:00:00 CEST 2016
Output date String: 2016-08-01T08:00:00 WEST
```

You can see that Output date String is still expressed in WEST.

If, for instance, I change the initial dateStrIn to: `String dateStrIn = "2016-08-01T08:00:00 GMT";`, then the Output date String is expressed in CEST as espected:

```
Output date String: 2016-08-01T10:00:00 CEST
```

Could it be a bug?

**UPDATE 2:**

Another example

```
Default TimeZone for both Date and SimpleDateFormat: "Europe/Paris"
Input String: "2016-08-01T08:00:00 WET"
```

Output:

```
Date.toString() Mon Aug 01 10:00:00 CEST 2016
Output date String: 2016-08-01T09:00:00 WEST
```

Notice that `dateFormat.format(date);` has produced a WEST date string. From WET -> WEST when it should be WET -> CEST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this mystery was on the Javadoc:

`DateFormat.parse(String source, ParsePosition pos)`

> This parsing operation uses the calendar to produce a Date. As a
>   result, the calendar's date-time fields and the TimeZone value may
>   have been overwritten, depending on subclass implementations. Any
>   TimeZone value that has previously been set by a call to setTimeZone
>   may need to be restored for further operations.

Setting the TimeZone after parsing works it out:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss z");
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));

System.out.println("Current Timezone: " + TimeZone.getDefault());

String dateStrIn = "2016-08-01T08:00:00 WET";
Date date = dateFormat.parse(dateStrIn);
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Paris"));
String dateStrOut = dateFormat.format(date);

System.out.println("Input date String: "+dateStrIn);
System.out.println("Date.toString() "+date);
System.out.println("Output date String: "+dateStrOut);
```

Right output:

```
Current Timezone: sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Paris",offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=184,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Paris,offset=3600000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=3600000,startTimeMode=2,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=3600000,endTimeMode=2]]
Input date String: 2016-08-01T08:00:00 WET
Date.toString() Mon Aug 01 10:00:00 CEST 2016
Output date String: 2016-08-01T10:00:00 CEST
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of setting the default time zone, set the time zone on your `SimpleDateFormat` object:

```
dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

This will make the `SimpleDateFormat` object format your `Date` object in the `UTC` time zone.

If you're using Java 8, consider using the new date and time API in the package `java.time` instead of the old `java.util.Date` and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

Comment: Thanks Jesper, it works...well almost, always, can you have a look at the updated answer?

Comment: I just submitted it

Comment: @codependent I don't have time to look at it in detail right now but it is highly unlikely that there is such a bug in Java's old date and time API which nobody has noticed in the past 20 years.

Comment: @codependent things to keep in mind: (1) a `java.util.Date` object does not know its timezone, (2) `Date.toString` uses the system's default time zone.

Comment: Got it. But for some strange reason the configured timezone in the SimpleDateFormat doesn't work when using a WEST timezone as input.

Answer (score 1):

You torture yourself by using the troublesome old legacy date-time classes now outmoded by the java.time framework.

## tl;dr

```
ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( Instant.parse( "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z" ) , ZoneId.of( "Europe/Paris" ) )
```

## java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`. The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) team also advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

## `Instant`

The `Z` on the end of your input string `2016-08-01T00:00:00Z` is short for `Zulu` and means [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Represented in java.time by the `Instant` class with a resolution up to nanoseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse ( "2016-08-01T00:00:00Z" );
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

Specify a time zone via `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime`.

In the summer, [Paris time](http://time.is/Paris) is two hours ahead of UTC. So the same moment as seen on a clock on the wall in Paris is 2 AM rather than midnight, on same date of August 1st.

```
ZoneId zoneId_Paris = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Paris" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Paris = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId_Paris );
```

You can adjust into another time zone such as [`Atlantic/Canary`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic/Canary). For this date in the summer, the time is one hour ahead of UTC. Result is 1 AM rather than midnight.

```
ZoneId zoneId_Canary = ZoneId.of ( "Atlantic/Canary" );
ZonedDateTime zdt_Canary = zdt_Paris.withZoneSameInstant ( zoneId_Canary );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "instant: " + instant + " | zdt_Paris: " + zdt_Paris + " | zdt_Canary: " + zdt_Canary );
```

> instant: 2016-08-01T00:00:00Z | zdt_Paris: 2016-08-01T02:00+02:00[Europe/Paris] | zdt_Canary: 2016-08-01T01:00+01:00[Atlantic/Canary]

All three of these objects (UTC, Paris, Canary) represent the very same *simultaneous* moment in history, the same single point on the timeline. Each is viewed through the lens of a different [wall-clock time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wall-clock_time).

## Real Time Zones

**Avoid 3-4 letter zone abbreviations** such as `WET` and `WEST`. These are *not* real time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

[`Europe/Paris`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) and [`Atlantic/Canary`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic/Canary) are [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones), in the format of `continent/region`.

Comment: Basil thanks for the suggestion, I have already played with this new API. Unfortunately it's not a self torture passion :-), I have to work with JDK 1.6 since our app servers don't support JDK 1.8.

Comment: @codependent Note the mention and link to [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) for Java 6 & 7. Just add a jar to your project.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, its not a bug.

You have to first understand how [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) class works. It is nothing but a wrapper over the number of milliseconds since the `epoch`, expressed in *long*. Hence, whichever timezone it may be, the underlying value of the date object remains the same. You can never really change the timezone of a `Date` class. You can only represent a `String` format of a date instance using a `SimpleDateFormat` class. This representation might have different time zones, based on which you are using while creating the `SimpleDateFormat`object.

Again, you need to check the [toString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) method of the Date class. It always prints the date with the default time zone.

**Edit**

You should look at the [SimpleDateFormat.parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)) definition as well. The JDK says that,

> The TimeZone value may be overwritten, depending on the given pattern and the time zone value in text. Any TimeZone value that has previously been set by a call to setTimeZone may need to be restored for further operations.

Comment: That doesn't explain what's going on in dateFormat.format(date). I configured the SimpleDateFormat's time zone to be Europe/Paris (CEST currently) but it doesn't output the formated String as expected.